# Can not read image using WebClient if img src does not contain an image file name

Tags: html, image, webclient

I am trying to download an image using a WebClient. The image source does not contain a path to image file, rather it contains a query with parameter as follows"

```
src="getphoto.action?memberInfo.memberNumber=123" alt="no image"
```

My WebClient returns HTML rather than an image. The returned HTML starts with:

```
<!-- Header Begin -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head >
    <title> 
        Technical Error
    </title>
```

Most likely the image is being grabbed dynamically from a database based on member ID. When I point to the image's `src` in Chrome DevTools, Chrome successfully displays image thumbnail.

Why am I not able to get the image from its `src` attribute?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question lacks context and the steps you have already tried to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can use Ajax  javascript to get the page with html.And you can interpret the request incoming from that page and extract the image from the html code.
Something like this:

```
 //here include Jquery for more detail go to W3school jquery
 var pageid=1
 var url="getphoto.action?memberInfo.memberNumber="+pageid;
  $.ajax({
    url: url, 
    success: function(result){
       //here interpret the html code incoming to  extract the page
       //you can use Jquery or Javascript

  }});
```

2)Or you can try to use an iframe to show that image

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I downloaded the HTML response using the following code                                                
               WebClient client = new WebClient();
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36");
                    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "jpeg,jfif,png");
                    webClient.DownloadFile(img source, "response.txt");
                }.

Comment: I opened the htlm with text editor. The html page does not contain any reference to the image. It contains functions, ajax code and html tags that exist in the same page that contains the image source

Comment: The image has to be stored somewhere

Comment: If I paste the full address including getphoto.action?memberInfo.memberNumber=123 into Chrome URL address bar, Chrome successfully downloads the image into download folder provided I log into the site first otherwise I get an error message from the website. I am using Selenium C# to scrape data and images after logging into the web site. Could cookies have any link to the error I am getting when trying to download the image using webclient? Do I need to pass credentials in the Http request although i am already logged into the site using Selenium

Comment: I finally could solve the problem. Its all about cookies. When I looped over Selenium cookies using webdriver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies and created corresponding .net cookies and added them to httpRequest.CookieContainer. Now HttpWebResponse instead of returning uri of the error page that i get in case i paste image source into Chrome address bar without logging into the web site. it seems that cookies contains credentials and session id that are necessiry to download the image.

Comment: If I helped you please check the sign in the left of my post